# Use Terminal to duplicate file multiple times and rename files based on contents of .txt file

Tags: terminal

I have a single file called template.indd within a folder. I want to make multiple copies of the file (hundreds) within the same folder, but rename each copy with names contained in a text file. The names in the text file are random, non-sequential, and separated by spaces.

I am using Terminal in Mac OSX, version 10.6.8.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**`xargs` solution**

Gnu Bash:

```
xargs -a file.txt -n 1 cp template.indd
```

On Mac (thx @ Stéphane Chazelas)

```
xargs -n 1 < file.txt cp template.indd
```

---

**Explanation**

- `-a` (`--arg-file`): Read items from file (only GNU Bash)
- `<` non-GNU alternative for `-a`
- `-n 1` (`--max-args`): add one item only for each run
- `cp template.indd`: the command xargs runs with the item added

Comment: `ln` will make one file with many names.

Comment: ah yeah true, not good idea if OP wants to edit the copies... I'll remove that suggestion.

Comment: `-a`  is a GNU extension not supported by macOS `xargs`. Use `xargs -n 1 < file.txt cp template.indd`.

Comment: Note that it assumes file names don't contain tabs, newlines, single quotes, double quotes or backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where `file.txt` is the file containing the filenames:

```
for file in $(cat file.txt);do cp template.indd "${file}";done
```